# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, linq, casting, int

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
public List<int> GetRolesForAccountByEmail(string email)
{
    var account = db.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Email == email);
    if (account == null) return new List<int>();

    return db.AccountRoles.Where(a => a.AccountId == account.AccountId).Select(a => Convert.ToInt32(a.RoleId)).ToList();
}
```

I had to convert to Int32 because I could not return a `List<int?>` when the method was to return a `List<int>`.

Any suggestions on how to solve this simple problem?

Comment: I think the `Convert` functions won't work with LINQ to Entities, is it possible that you could do a `db.AccountRules.AsEnumerable()` and then the rest

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
Select(a => Convert.ToInt32(a.RoleId))
```

Do this:

```
Select(a => a.RoleId.Value)
```

The reason is in the error description; when you are doing these queries through IQueryable, the methods being used within the selector have to be something that can be translated into a SQL query or function. In this case `Convert.ToInt32()` is not such a method. For `int` fields with `null` allowed, using the .NET `.Value` property does work, though.

Note that this would not work if your `RoldId` is `null`, however. You'll get an `InvalidOperationException`. You might want to return a set value instead if the backing field is null:

```
Select(a => a.RoleId.HasValue ? a.RoleId.Value : int.MinValue)
```

This will return the value if there is one, and `int.MinValue` if not.

Answer (score 6):

Use this:
Select(a => (int)a.RoleId)

Comment: This worked for me. @AndrewBarber's answer didn't. Thanks muthuvel.

Comment: Yep this one worked where the others didn't - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to take List object from the db.Accounts and do the stuff.
It works for me.

```
public List<int> GetRolesForAccountByEmail(string email)
{
    var account = db.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Email == email);
    if (account == null) return new List<int>();
    return db.AccountRoles.Where(a => a.AccountId == account.AccountId).Select(a => Convert.ToInt32(a.RoleId)).ToList();
}
```

Instead of this, try this..

```
public List<int> GetRolesForAccountByEmail(string email)
    {
    var account = db.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Email == email);
    if (account == null) return new List<int>();
    List<AccountRoles> accountRoles= db.AccountRoles.ToList<AccountRoles>();
    return accountRoles.Where(a => a.AccountId == account.AccountId).Select(a => Convert.ToInt32(a.RoleId)).ToList();
    }
```