# LINQ result to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, razor

What's a simple way to return the result of a LINQ query to a view?

I have a LINQ query in my controller that gets a result from a database but am kinda lost on how to return it to a view.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (Session["UserId"] == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
    }
    else
    {    
        EmployeeHomeViewModel model = new EmployeeHomeViewModel();

        var UserId = from x in db.Employees
                     where x.Employee_Id == Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"])
                     select x;

        //DISPLAY RESULT       

        var project = from x in db.Projects
                      where x.Employee_Id == Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"])
                      select x;
        foreach (Project result in project)
        {
            model.Project.Project_Id = result.Project_Id;
            model.Project.Project_Name = result.Project_Name;
            model.Project.Project_Detail = result.Project_Detail;             
        }

        //DISPLAY RESULT

    }

    return View();
}
```

**View:**

```
@model ProjectManager.ViewModels.EmployeeHomeViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<div>Hello, @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Employee.Employee_FirstName)</div><br />
<div>Current project: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Project.Project_Id)</div><br />
<div>Project name: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Project.Project_Name)</div><br />
<div>Details: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Project.Project_Detail)</div><br />
```

**Model:**

```
public class EmployeeHomeViewModel
{
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }        
}
```

***Edit:***

To be clear, before even being able to return the LINQ query's result to a view, I have to fix an error that occurs executing the query in my foreach loop:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `return View();` with `return View(model);`.

Several overloads of the [`Controller.View` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx) are available to support specifying as much as you need to return the `ViewResult` you desire.  In this case, you need the `Controller.View(Object)` overload rather than the parameterless `Controller.View()` overload; the `Object` parameter of the former is to specify the model on which you would like to base the returned `ViewResult`.

Comment: Did it, but I got this error in my foreach.

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: That is [an entirely different question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10117681/1810429)...[that has already been answered on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10117941/1810429).  (Basically, add `.Value` to the end of each statement in your `foreach`.)

Comment: I can't.. there's no .Value method.

Comment: @RoyalFlash: Yes, sorry to too quickly map the linked Q&A in my comment to your situation.  The linked Q&A are still relevant; but you need to leverage them as @StanleyD suggests.  Otherwise, you will still need to return a `ViewResult` based on `model` as I answered of course.

Answer (score 0):

> I got this error in my foreach.
>
> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method `'Int32 ToInt32(System.Object)'` method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

EF does not directly support the `Convert.ToInt32()` method. In your case it's an easy enough fix - just convert the session variable outside of the query (and reuse it):

```
    int userID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]);

    //DISPLAY RESULT       

    var project = from x in db.Projects
                  where x.Employee_Id == userID
                  select x;
```

A few other things I see:

- You are not using the `UserId` query at all
- You are iterating over the results of the `project` query but overwriting the same values each time.  I suspect your `EmployeeHomeViewModel` model should have a *collection* of projects instead of a single project.

Comment: @D Stanley
1) Yeah, I'l just copy paste the code for the project query when it works.
2) I'm only fetching 1 result anyway. Know a more efficient way?

Thank you for answering..

edit: got an error pointing to the first statement of my foreach

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Add '.Single()` after your query to only get one object.