# Linq To Entities - run CONVERT to int on DB

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linqpad

My table in DB contains varchar field which contains both string and integer values. Requirement is compare only integers with provided value.
This code

```
from c in Cars
where SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(c.Code) 
      && Convert.ToInt32(c.Code) == 12
```

throws

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Runing this query in LINQPad is working fine! Why?

Question: How to Convert string directly in db and compare with provided integer value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117681/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-int32-toint32system-object-me)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
from c in Cars
where c.Code == "12"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.